# How do i use a backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a backgroundworker in the designer. Set the option WorkerReportsProgress and WorkerSupportsCancellations to true.
Also added all the three events of the backgroundworker.

Now i have timer1 tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter += 1;
            label9.Text = counter.ToString();
            label9.Visible = true;            
        }
```

I havea method called it NewsUpdate:

```
private void NewsUpdate()
        {
            if (counter == 10)
            {
                scrollLabel1.Reset();
                scrollLabel1.Text = " ";
                scrollLabel1.Invalidate();
                client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
                page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
                TextExtractor.ExtractDateTime(page, newText, dateTime);
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
                w.Write(page);
                w.Close();
                TextExtractor.ExtractText(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html", newText, dateTime);
                combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newText);
                this.scrollLabel1.Text = combindedString;
                scrollLabel1.Invalidate();
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
```

And all the backgroundworker events:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            NewsUpdate();
        }
```

Progress:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Completed:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

What i want to do is to call each 10 seconds to the method NewsUpdate through the backgroundworker so it will not freeze the application for 1-2 seconds each time it's making an update. But now it's calling the NewsUpdate method only once.

1. How do i use the backgroundworker with the NewsUpdate method ?
2. What should i add if at all in each of the events of the backgroundworker ?
3. Are there any methods or files in the NewsUpdate method that the backgroundworker will throw exception on them since it's ui or something ?

Comment: I don't see the creation of the `BackgroundWorker` in your code, but assuming you have it, you mostly just want to have your `DoWork` handler call `worker.ReportProgress()` every ten seconds. That calls the `ProgressChanged` handler, which can interact with the UI. MSDN has a [decent example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx).

Comment: First of all: Your timer and backgroundworker are two separate things, nothing connects them together. You should call your backgroundworker's DoWork method in your Timer's tick. Also, you are modifying UI components (this.scrollLabel1.Text) in your BackgroundWorker's DoWork method, which you should avoid. Do that in your RunWorkerCompleted method which will run in the STA thread. And finally: most probably you won't need the ProgressChanged callback.

Comment: qqbenq do you mean i should use backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); in the timer1 tick event ? This is how i call the DoWork event in the timer1 tick event ?

Comment: Use the System.Windows.Forms.Timer class for that.